# Set of Integers. How many does it contain? AMC 2003 Senior(Australia)

Tags: contest-math

A set of positive integers has the properties that

- Every member in th set, apart form 1, is divisible by at least one of $2,3,$ or $5$.
- If the set contains $2n, 3n,$ or $5n$ for some integer $n$, then it contains all three and $n$ as well.

The set contains between $300$ and $400$ numbers. Exactly how many does it contain?

I started with $\{1,2,3,5\}$, and tried to add some more numbers: say when $n=2$, we can add $2\times2=4, 3\times2=6, 5\times2=10$, it became $\{1,2,3,5,4,6,10\}$. Now we had $6=2\times3$, which $n=3$, we should add $3\times3=9$ and $5\times3=15$. Also $10=2\times5$, we need to add $3\times5=15$ and $5\times5=25$. Now we had set $\{1,2,3,5,4,6,10,9,15,25\}$. But this step is too slow, and I got lost finally.

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format your question.

Comment: Knowing $2$ is in the set does not tell you $4,6,10$ are in the set, but knowing $4$ is in the set tells you $2,6,10$ are in the set as well as $1,3,5,9,15,25$

Answer (score 6):

Here are some hints:

- Any number belonging to the set is of the form $2^a3^b5^c$ for some non-negative $a, b$ and $c$.
- If $2^a3^b5^c$ lies in the set the so does every number of the form $2^s3^t5^u$ where $s+t+u \le a+b+c$.